# vert centered row before subequations/align environment similar to cases enviroment

Tags: align, subequations

I would like to have a vertically centered row before the first math env defined with subequations similar to the second example defined with cases. It is possible to accomplish that in a standard and easy way? (I don't like the second example due to the weird spacing, align is perfect. I need the subequations to reference inner rows
Source:

```
\begin{subequations}
  S:
  \label{eq:abcd}
  \begin{align}
    \label{eq:ab}
    \matr{a} &= \matr{b}\\
    \label{eq:cd}
    \matr{c} &= \matr{d}
  \end{align}
\end{subequations}

\begin{equation}
  S:
  \label{eq:abcd}
  \begin{cases}
    \matr{a} &= \matr{b}\\
    \matr{c} &= \matr{d}
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `empheq`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{empheq} % also loads amsmath

\newcommand{\matr}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}

\begin{document}

% let's get the same output as you
\setcounter{chapter}{2}
\setcounter{equation}{1}

\begin{subequations}\label{eq:abcd}
\begin{empheq}[left={S{:}\empheqlbrace}]{align}
    \label{eq:ab}
    \matr{a} &= \matr{b}\\
    \label{eq:cd}
    \matr{c} &= \matr{d}
\end{empheq}
\end{subequations}

\ref{eq:abcd} and \ref{eq:ab} and \ref{eq:cd}

\end{document}
```

[image]